# Updated: Ignore finger resting on touchpad - Lenovo Yoga 700

Tags: touchpad, lenovo

I just got my new Lenovo Yoga 700 laptop, and I would like to disable the lower part of the touchpad so I can keep my finger on the button, while using my other finger to drag the mouse around.

Edit:
I have attempted to fix this in several ways for the past 24 hours, and the closest I got to it was using either:

```
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps (Can now drag finger, but it is laggy)
```

The other way was installing the mtrack driver (following this tutorial: http://yarenty.blogspot.no/2014/08/how-to-fix-macbook-pro-touchpad-on.html), but in this case the right-click button did not work at all. I did however the the right-click menu when I tapped the pad with two or more fingers.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score -1):

Due to poor touchpad support for Ubuntu, I have decided to use this solution:

Add to `/etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.conf`:

```
options psmouse proto=exps
```